# Eclipse Ganymede - Integeration with Tomcat 6 (without the whole WTP)

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-plugin

If I start with a [Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (85 MB)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) (Ganymede) installation. What plug ins do I need to install to be a able to:

- See the Server tab and being able to add my Tomcat 6 installation.
- Be able to create a Dynamic Web Project which I may connect to my server.
- I want to be able to start and stop the server.
- See the server Stdout-output in my Console tab.
- Debug an application on the server.

I want to install as little as possible, as long as I can do the above things I am more than satisfied.

Especially since I have problems with the complete Web Tools Platform (WTP); according to *me* it's full of bugs related to validation. It sometimes says valid files are invalid, often it helps if you simply restart Eclipse. I have also found it to ignore exclusions as well as sometimes completely ignoring that I have disabled validation all together.

The problems I've experienced have made me uninterested in anything from the WTP project, *except* the plug ins enabling me to work more smoothly by fulfilling the above unordered list (because that part of WTP worked really well).

I have heard the some have had success with [Sysdeo Eclipse Tomcat Launcher Plug-in](http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html) together with Ganymede. But since it's officially not supported and there has not been a new release since May 2007 and running it with Ganymede involved changing the plug-in files to accept versions >=3.4 I don't see it as a long term solution.

Installing **parts** of the **WTP** but **not it in its whole** feels like a long term solution while at the same time skipping the error ridden parts of the WTP. But I need help with which parts I need to install, as the documentation on Eclipse.org does not explain. Of course, if there is another supported solution than using parts of WTP then that is of interest too!

Comment: For what it's worth: I also had a lot of validation errors with WTP, but the latest update solved them all. The tricky part was realizing that for some obscure reason WTP updates weren't enabled by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I display the "eclipse Plug-in Dependencies" view for `org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.ui`, I see:

- org.eclipse.wst.common.emf
- org.eclipse.wst.common.emfwrokben.integration
- org.eclipse.wst.common.environment
- org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks
- org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore
- org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core
- org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui
- org.eclipse.wst.common.uriresolver
- org.eclipse.wst.internet.monitor.core
- org.eclipse.wst.server.core
- org.eclipse.wst.server.ui
- org.eclipse.wst.validation

So if you can select `org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.ui` through p2 and let that "update process" to pick the dependencies for you, you should end up with the minimal set of plugins needed for running/managing Tomcat on Eclipse (with WTP).

Comment: I can't find org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.ui in "Help / Software Updates...". I searched for it, and I search for Tomcat, then I tired Google, but nothing. Do you have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: True, another option would be to install all WTP in a separate eclipse installation, and then copy only the aforementionned plugins in your dropin directory in your current eclipse installation.